# Collaborative Filtering Recommender Systems as a regression ( rating 1 to 10) or classification (0 or 1)

Tags: recommender-system

we solve a Collaborative Filtering Recommender Systems as a regression ( rating 1 to 10) or classification (0 or 1) why we see that a lot of works in Collaborative Filtering Recommender Systems change the rating from (1 to 10) to (binary rating 1 and 0)??

Comment: My guess: normalization.